# How can I create simple view engine like Mustache {{ }} using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, viewengine

How can I create simple view engine like Mustache, so that the word between the {{ }} is replaced by its value, like:

```
<p>hey there {{ codeName }}</p>
codeName = 'JavaScript 6'
so that it be converted to:

<p>hey there JavaScript 6</p>
```

Comment: If this technique was actually that simple, Mustache wouldn't need to exist. I'd use Mustache or something like it so you don't have to deal with the issues they already have.

Comment: @Blazemonger it is not to have the solution, I want to understand the solution, not just use it.

Comment: I must say this question has been unfairly 'put on hold' as there are literally thousands upon thousands of questions on SO which ask for specific *broad* things such as this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below to be proper way to understand it:

```
var templater = function(html){
  return function(data){
  for(var x in data){
    var re = "{{\\s?" + x + "\\s?}}";
    html = html.replace(new RegExp(re, "ig"), data[x]);
  }
  return html;
 };
};

var template = new templater("<p>hey there {{ codeName }}</p>");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = template({
  codeName: "JavaScript 6"
 });
 document.body.appendChild(div);
```

reference is [here](http://jsforallof.us/2014/12/01/the-anatomy-of-a-simple-templating-engine/)