# Creating simple view engine using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, viewengine

How can I create simple view engine using JavaScript like Mustache, so that the word between the `{{ }}` is replaced by its value, like:

```
<p>hey there {{ codeName }}</p>
codeName = 'JavaScript 6'
```

so that it be converted to:

```
<p>hey there JavaScript 6</p>
```

Comment: You literally just asked that question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006047/

Comment: @AdamKonieska I forced to re-ask it, because some people put the other one on hold, without offering solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below to be proper way:

```
var templater = function(html){
  return function(data){
  for(var x in data){
    var re = "{{\\s?" + x + "\\s?}}";
    html = html.replace(new RegExp(re, "ig"), data[x]);
  }
  return html;
 };
};

var template = new templater("<p>hey there {{ codeName }}</p>");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = template({
  codeName: "JavaScript 6"
 });
 document.body.appendChild(div);
```

reference is [here](http://jsforallof.us/2014/12/01/the-anatomy-of-a-simple-templating-engine/)